# How to debug java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` that when clicked it will show the multiple image path stored in a `Database`. When clicking Row 1 up to the last row it shows the multiple images path in `TextView`. But my problem is that when Row 0 is clicked the app crashes.

Here is my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flip);
        txtLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.samp);

        Intent goFlip = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = goFlip.getExtras();
        String getLocation = bundle.getString("path");
        index =bundle.getInt("pos");

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        dbList = new ArrayList<GettersSetters>();
        dbList = db.searchFromDB(getLocation);

        String locate = "";
        if(dbList.size() > 0 ){

            for(GettersSetters currentClass : dbList){
                locate +=dbList.get(index-1).getPath() + ",";
                Log.w("RESULT PATHS", locate);
            }

        }
        txtLoc.setText(locate);
    }
```

It produces the following **error**.

```
09-09 17:33:39.141 24147-24147/com.luminous.pick E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.luminous.pick/com.luminous.pick.FlipActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
at com.luminous.pick.FlipActivity.onCreate(FlipActivity.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: Your stacktrace says that the problem is that you're calling index `-1`. I see a potential in your get(index-1) call.

Comment: ```locate +=dbList.get(index-1).getPath() + ",";``` here is this line have error. index -1 will return -1 when index = 0

Comment: @xenteros I try removing -1 but still Im having an error

Comment: @DanhDC I try removing -1 but still it produces this error:

 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare index globally

```
 int index=0;
```

and use this method instead of yours....

```
 for(GettersSetters currentClass : dbList){
                locate +=dbList.get(index++).getPath() + ",";
                Log.w("RESULT PATHS", locate);
            }
```

Comment: you are welcome ....

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to subtract 1 from index because you are getting -1 if index equals 0.